# Variable that I point to using this keyword is not used

Tags: java, class, this

I am trying build a method(showCost) that takes in the product number and return the cost of the product.My second method is where the error occurs.

I am trying to use the this keyword to point the payment to my local variable payment amount.However, the program says that my paymentamount variable is not used.

```
 public class CashRegister {
        Double [] cost = {3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0};
        private Double paymentamount;

    public Double showCost (int productnum){
        return (cost[productnum]);
    }

    public void payAmount(double payment){
        this.paymentamount = payment;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"[T]he program says that my paymentamount variable is not used."* The program is right. You're not using that variable anywhere, just assigning a value to it.

Comment: add a getter for that field, or a method that treats the content, and your "problem" will be solved. Having an unused variable is not a blocking issue, you'll still be able to build and use the code

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. If you have plans to use that variable later then that's fine.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen    I thought this.paymentamount indicates that I am using paymentamount variable?

Comment: Since I am assigning a value to it.

Comment: Assigning != using

Comment: You are writing it but not reading it.

Comment: so meaning when I called the method in other class , this warning will disappear right?

Comment: No, meaning when you add some code that reads it in *this* class the warning will disappear. No other class can read it, because it's `private`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program says that paymentamount variable is not used.

Because: You're just assigning the value in paymentamount variable, but you are not using that variable anywhere else.